# Networking packet and data

Tags: networking, https, packet

What is the difference between packets and data in any of the network models (TCP/IP) or (OSI) models? And please add some examples in the answer.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

A data is a collection of packets.
A packet is sub part of data which contains some header bits along with the message bits.

Each packet consists of three distinct parts, each of which each part contains some of the components listed above: **Header**: typically includes an alert signal to indicate that the data is being transmitted, **source and destination addresses** and **clock information** to synchronise the transmission.

[image]

As you can see in this the message is divided into chunks and then from the application layer it adds the header bits and recieve to the transport layer and then in consecutive layers each layer add its header bits.

Answer (score 0):

Packets are data units within the network layer in the OSI model. Also in TCP/IP model, it will be an in-network layer. This is practically always IP. This involves adding a source and destination IP address.

Data will be at the Application layer in the OSI model. In addition in TCP / IP model, it will be at the application layer.

So the difference between packet and data is each one at a different layer. Also, it does not have the same component, because the message move between the layers and varies in each layer.